# How can I parse a twitter HTML page using PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, twitter

I read a lot of articles explaining how to parse a HTML file with PHP but in the case of twitter it uses iframe where texts are hidden. How can I parse the twitter HTML?

I know it is very easy to use API's or .rss page or json to get the tweets/string but I want to be able to work with twitter HTML page directly. Is there any way I could find the tweets using their html page?

Comment: So your question is not actually about parsing. Make it reflect that page downloading is the real problem.

Comment: @mario I edited. What I had in mind was - I wanted to save the page source and work on parsing offline. It is the same as working online but I've just started coding so that's why I tried to save a page and work offline.

Comment: @Instellar_Coder I don't care if it changes in future. My goal now would be to download like say 1000 html twitter pages and do my work (parsing) on that. I care only about the information that is there till now. The reason I don't want API is I'm parsing several other websites HTML pages and incorporate twitter's HTML page. So basically I'm trying to make it universally just parsing HTML pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use something like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). With this you can use CSS selectors like with jQuery to find the elements on the page you are looking for. However Twitter pages use a lot of javascript and ajax so you may be stuck with either using an API or maybe you could try it with the mobile site.

Comment: The problem is I'm not able to find the element. I'm not able to find the tweets from the HTML page

Comment: I think that's because most of the content is loaded on to the page dynamically using AJAX. That's why I would suggest trying the mobile site instead. Otherwise if you want to do it manually you could use Firebug (or something similar) to get the live HTML from the page then you can parse that.

Comment: That's is a nice idea but is it possible to automate the process ?

Comment: If you're only using PHP then only on the mobile site. Otherwise you could try using [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) and jQuery (or another JS library) to collect the details then send them to a PHP script for processing.